# Drupal 8 translatable configuration

Tags: configuration, drupal-8, translate, access-denied

I'm trying to setup a custom module that provide content from an API.The API url is configurable, but as it is different for each language I must be able to translate it. I setup my module configuration as described [here](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/creating-custom-modules/defining-and-using-your-own-configuration-in-drupal-8) (see the gist below) but when I try to access the translation form from /admin/config/regional/config-translation, i get "Access denied"

What am I doing wrong ?

https://gist.github.com/julien-maitan/ffd136bc104d3dbe2ee526367ffcb44c

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all,

1. Does your custom permission `configure crtib configurator` is defined in a `permissions.yml` file ? And did you give this permission to your user ?
2. Where is your config/install settings file ? In your case your `crtib_configurator.settings.yml` ? Did you miss it ?

These files are not mandatory by default in Drupal 8, but are required once we want to make your configuration translatable.

---

I would suggest you this 2 articles:

- [Drupal 8 - How to translate the Config API](https://antistatique.net/en/we/blog/2018/05/01/drupal-8-how-to-translate-the-config-api)
- [Drupal 8 multilingual tidbits 16: configuration translation development](http://hojtsy.hu/blog/2014-may-26/drupal-8-multilingual-tidbits-16-configuration-translation-development)

---

*Update* - With Review of Google Drive Files

1. `config` folder should be placed in the **root** of your module **not** in `src`;
2. `crtib_configurator.links.task.yml` use a wrong route_name `crtib_configurator.api_settings_translate`, it should be `crtib_configurator.api_settings`.

Apply those 2 changes & clear your cache, you will then be able to use the translations form properly.

I think the main & initial error was the `config` folder location.

**Directory structure:**

```
.
+-- crtib_configurator 
|   +-- config
|   |  +-- install
|   |  |  +--  crtib_configurator.api.yml
|   |  +-- schema
|   |  |  +--  crtib_configurator.schema.yml
|   +-- src
|    |  +-- Form
|    |  |  +-- SettingsForm.php
|   +-- crtib_configurator.config_translation.yml
|   +-- crtib_configurator.info.yml
|   +-- crtib_configurator.links.menu.yml
|   +-- crtib_configurator.links.task.yml
|   +-- crtib_configurator.permissions.yml
|   +-- crtib_configurator.routing.yml
```

**Content of `crtib_configurator.links.task.yml`:**

```
crtib_configurator.api_settings:
  route_name: crtib_configurator.api_settings
  title: 'CRTIB configurator settings'
  base_route: crtib_configurator.api_settings
```

Comment: custom permissions are defined in `crtib_configurator.permissions.yml`. user was granted permissions. even the super adminsitrator get an access denied. settings file is in `src/config/install/crtib_configurator.settings.yml`, schema is in `src/config/schema/crtib_configurator.schema.yml`, other files are in the module root directory.
 I added `crtib_configurator.links.task.yml` file has suggested in the first article

I still get access denied

Comment: Could you please add your code from `\Drupal\crtib_configurator\Form\SettingsForm` & `crtib_configurator.permissions.yml` here or in your gist.

Comment: Plus, could you upload your module `crtib_configurator` as a zip somehwere ? So I would be able to install it & saw the error, it's maybe a typo in the folders/files structure.

Comment: I tried to changes some names since last Gist but without success. Here is the last version of my module : https://drive.google.com/open?id=1blRbUOZq0gF1Aj7VtTNgVcvIyKgS55le

Comment: I updated my answer with a final contribution to fix your issue. I test it on my sandbox environment & it works properly now. I think the main & initial error was the `config` folder location, see me complete answer.

Comment: Thank you [Kevin Wenger](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4770218/kevin-wenger). You point me to the right direction. The config folder was in the wrong place.